# CartoDB layer selector - selecting data from 2 layers

Tags: sql, carto, select, query-layer

I used the CartoDB layer selector example (http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/layer_selector.html) with my data. Works fine. Now, what I really want to do is to select data from 2 layers at the same time - not from only one as it is the case now.

The second layer I want to select from is subLayer(3) and the sql would be the same as the first one: "select * from all_lachine2014_post where eventdist =  " + event;

(the subLayer(3) table name is all_lachine2014_post)

I have tried a few things - but can't figure out how to create a second selector and have the sql combined to select from my two tables at the same time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Layer selector example | CartoDB.js</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #layer_selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #layer_selector ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  #layer_selector li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 12px 22px;
    font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    cursor: auto;
  }
  #layer_selector li:hover {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #layer_selector li.selected {
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="layer_selector" class="cartodb-infobox">
  <ul>
    <li data="21" class="selected">Parcours 21.1 km</li>
    <li data="10">Parcours 10 km</li>
    <li data="5">Parcours 5 km</li>
    <li data="2">Parcours 1 et 2 km</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js"></script>

<script>
  // create layer selector
  function createSelector(layer) {
    var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'documentation' });
    var $options = $('#layer_selector li');
    $options.click(function(e) {
      // get the area of the selected layer
      var $li = $(e.target);
      var event = $li.attr('data');
      // deselect all and select the clicked one
      $options.removeClass('selected');
      $li.addClass('selected');
      // create query based on data from the layer
      var query = "select * from all_lachine2014_route ";
        query = "select * from all_lachine2014_route where eventdist =  " + event;
      //}
      // change the query in the layer to update the map
      layer.setSQL(query);
    });
  }
  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://veroterio.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/6a187d7e-991b-11e4-b012-0e9d821ea90d/viz.json', {
      center_lat: 45.433249,
      center_lon: -73.693418,
      zoom: 14

    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      // layer 0 is the base layer, layer 1 is cartodb layer
      var subLayer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
      createSelector(subLayer);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the entire layer by parameter to createSelector function. I mean:

`createSelector(layers[1])`

And then, in the function, you could select the sublayer that you really want depending on the clicked that you receive.

Comment: thanks you that works!! Also, do you know if we can select a Torque Layer? One of my layer is Torque and I would like to be able to set a SQL to it and show or hide depending on the clicked element. I can do it on my other layers, but it doesnt seem to work with Torque.

Comment: answer to my question above was given [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134399/can-we-hide-show-a-torque-layer-and-or-set-sql)

Comment: @veroterio , glad that it worked ^^